# How to access Sqlite DB file on a different system

Tags: sqlite

I have a java service running on one system and a Sqlite .db file on a different system. Found some examples on using sqlite jdbc driver, but they are accessing the .db files from the same system as java program. I also found that Sqlite doesn't have any username and password.

Is there any way to access the Sqlite .db file from a service running on different system?